# Specifyinf column length for a json colum in EF7

Tags: entity-framework-core

EF7 JSON columns are great. But I can't tell the model builder not to create a column as `nvarchar(max)`, but something smaller, as it is an overkill in my case. I know that `OwnsOne` is a generic method for embedded type definition, and `.ToJson` is an addition. The legacy way will create many columns. Hence the returned object's `Property` method is for the underlying properties, not the JSON column itself. But `ToJson` has no overload that accepts anything different from then column name.

Comment: Look at [Custom Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding/templates?tabs=dotnet-core-cli). You can change some definitions.